# export the excel camera picture as the PNG file

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the workbook which has two objects - chart and camera picture referencing this chart - maybe you can recommend how to export the camera picture as the PNG file? The PNG file name should be taken from a cell - eg. image1..

I have this code but it does not seem to work:

```
option explicit

sub biy_comara()
    dim spath as string
    dim rrng as object, sht as object
    
    set sht = thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet1")
    spath = thisworkbook.path & "\" & sht.range("d1").value & ".png"
    set rrng = sht.range("a2:c60")
    rrng.copypicture appearance:=xlscreen, format:=xlpicture
    
    with rrng.parent.chartobjects.add(10, 10, 200, 200)
        .shaperange.line.visible = msofalse
        .height = rrng.height
        .width = rrng.width
        .chart.paste
        .chart.export filename:=spath, filtername:="png"
        .delete
    end with
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but it currently is the correct answer:

The Excel VBA Object Model does not have a command for this action. The command has been added to the Excel context menu for the right-click on the object only a short time ago, and the VBA Object Model has not been adjusted to reflect that.

Whether or not such a command will be added going forward is not clear at the moment.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you - there still has to be a way!) at the very least I can use a plugin which allows to export all images in a worksheet - for now I just need to be able to rename the camera object - can you recommend a way to do that?

Comment: I just tested the above macro and it was able to export cell range with camera object to a png file - my production workbook must be too large for it to work

Comment: I've reached out to Jon Peltier, who is an expert for Excel VBA. He may have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The above macro effectively overcomes excels vba limitations and exports a camera image as png using cell value as png name - I just had to move the camera image to a new complete clear worksheet and focus the camera on original overlaid charts.

Answer (score 0):

My Excel VBA solution

1. range.Select
2. range.CopyPicture
3. Paste it
4. Cut it for storing to system clipboard ( key-point )
5. create windows powershell command in one-line
6. execute powershell by Shell

```
Sub 巨集1()
 PicDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
 PicFile = Format(Now(), "hh-mm") & ".png"
    Sheets("工作表1").Select
    Range("Q1:U10").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture '複製範圍成圖檔
    ActiveSheet.Paste '要利用這動作-1，才會真的存到 Clipboard
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Selection.ShapeRange.Name)).Select '選剛貼上的 Shape
    Selection.Cut '要利用這動作-2，才會真的存到 Clipboard
    sPSCmd = "powershell $img = get-clipboard -format image ; $img.Save('" & PicDir & PicFile & "')" '把 Clipboard 內容存成圖檔的 PowerShell
    RetVal = Shell(sPSCmd, 0) '無聲無息的執行
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SU. You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774419/edit) the answer a bit. Firstly, you should change the Chinese text to English to make this understandable for an international audience. Secondly I'd suggest expanding the steps so that an absolute beginner (like me, for example) can also follow them.